# Importing parent package from child module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to import a package which is a parent package for a module inside that parent package. But i ma getting an error saying No Module Name Regression_Model. I need help on this. Please find the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, I tries doing relative import but still getting the same error:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.path` is where python looks for modules to find them.

In addition, when you run a script, python will automatically add it's directory to the `sys.path`. you may confirm it by printing it.

In your case `..../regression_model/config` directory is added(I skipped with "...."). Because there is no `regression_model` package in that directory, You have to manually add this code before import statement :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..../section-05-production-model-package')
```

Now python can find `regression_model` package inside above path that we added.

** instead of my "....", use absolute path to that directory in your OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few checks you can do, after that you can proceed to download it manually.

1. Go to IDLE and type `import regression_model`, doesn't work ? means it is not there.
2. go to `~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib` and try to find this library to verify that you have or not, check spelling of the folder if yes.
3. Finally base solution go to https://pypi.org/project/regression-model/#files download `tar.gz` , extract and inside you can find a folder named `regression_model`  and place it in `~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib` location

Now you retry the step 1 and you can import